# Peaceably vs. Peacefully

Tags: meaning, differences, meaning-in-context, synonyms, equivalence

What is the difference between "peaceably" and "peacefully"?

I found the word "peaceably" in the following text:

> Where the access and use of light or air to and for any building have been peaceably enjoyed therewith as an easement, and as of right, without interruption, and for twenty years, and where any way or watercourse or the use of any water or any other easement (whether affirmative or negative) has been peaceably and openly enjoyed by any person claiming title thereto as an easement and as of right without interruption and for twenty years, the right to such access and use of light or air, way, watercourse, use of water, or other easement shall be absolute and indefeasible. (Link: http://comtax.up.nic.in/Miscellaneous%20Act/limitation-act-1963.pdf)

What difference would have been there if, in the above text, the word "peacefully" would have been substituted for the word "peaceably"?

On googling, I found that "peaceful" means undisturbed by turmoil or disagreement and that "peaceable" means inclined to peace. (Link: http://grammarist.com/usage/peaceable-peaceful/) If it is so, then, in the above text, the word "peacefully" would have been better suited compared to the word "peaceably" used therein.

On a second thought, I find that the text, which states a provision of Indian law, is more than hundred years old and has stood the test of time. (The provision was there in the Indian Limitation Act, 1908 and has survived when that Act was re-enacted as the Indian Limitation Act, 1963.) If so, then it appears that there is perhaps no wrong in the use of the word "peaceably" in the above text.

Thus, the analysis finally takes me to no conclusion; confusion persists.

Can anybody tell me the correct scope of meaning of each of the two words − "peaceably" and "peacefully"?

Comment: I'd say they mean *exactly* the same thing. It's just that idiomatic usages change over time: today we nearly always use ***peacefully***, whereas a couple of centuries ago [we nearly always used ***peaceably***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=peaceably%2Cpeacefully&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpeaceably%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpeacefully%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about a legalese usage.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Are you saying *peaceably* is legal jargon, a technical term, or unnecessarily complicated? And I agree there are some questions that really need a legal expert to answer, but in this case I'm not really seeing it. It looks like a question about meaning that we can address here.

Comment: 'What difference would have been there if, in the above text, the word "peacefully" would have been substituted for the word "peaceably"?' gives a legal-domain-only constraint unacceptable on ELU. I see that the question has been revised to a certain extent since I close-voted, but it is still largely focused on the usage in the legal domain. Sven Yargs addresses this non-general scoping in his answer and a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Webster's Dictionary of Synonyms* (1942) groups *peaceable* and *peaceful* (along with *irenic*, *pacifist*, and *pacifistic*) under the entry for *pacific*:

> **Pacific, peaceable, peaceful,** ... are sometimes confused because they all involve the idea of affording or promoting peace. But **pacific** applies chiefly to persons, utterances, acts, influences, ideas, and the like, that tend to make peace or to conciliate strife; [examples omitted]. **Peaceable** applies also to persons, their actions, words, etc., but it describes their character or quality as peace-loving, as disposed top avoid strife, or as inclined to keep peace, rather than their aims or tendencies; [examples omitted]. **Peaceful** applies especially to a life, a condition or state, a period or age, a country or people, in which peace prevails or there is no strife, but it may apply to anything which manifests peace, especially peace of mind, or provides an opportunity for such peace; [examples omitted].

Thus, from this dictionary's point of view, the main difference between the two words is that *peaceably* indicates in a manner likely to maintain peace and minimize strife, while *peacefully* suggests in a manner demonstrating a state of peace and an absence of conflict.

With regard to the specifically legal meaning of *peaceable*, *Black's Law Dictionary*, revised fourth edition (1968) has this:

> **PEACEABLE.** Free from the character of force, violence, or trespass; as, a "peaceable entry" on lands. "Peaceable possession" of real estate is such as is acquiesced in by all other persons, including rival claimants, and not disturbed by any forcible attempt at ouster nor by adverse suits to recover the possession or the estate. [Citations omitted.]

Significantly, *Black's* does not include a legal definition of *peacefully*, from which we may deduce that *peacefully* is used far less often in statutes and ordinances than *peaceably* is. Often, English (and American) law will use fairly carefully defined terms across multiple jurisdictions in preference to very similar but less well-defined (in law) words. That appears to be what's going on with *peaceably* versus *peacefully*.

The key feature of peaceable possession or enjoyment of a thing appears to be possession or enjoyment without contention or dispute over many years. In the provision you refer to in your question, the rule has some elements in common with the law of adverse possession (namely, the openness and continuousness of the possession or enjoyment), and it serves somewhat similar ends (namely, not to upset a status quo that all interested parties have acquiesced in for many years).

---

***Conclusion***

*Peaceable* and *peaceful* have similar and largely overlapping meanings in everyday English, but they are not so completely interchangeable that a dictionary cannot distinguish different tendencies or colorations in their meaning.

But aside from the issue of whether the two terms mean different things in general usage, *peaceable* appears to be a much more distinctly defined and widely used term in the context of statutory law; and courts may have settled on a shared definition or interpretation of the terms "peaceable entry," "peaceable possession," and "peaceable enjoyment" that has no counterpart with regard to the terms "peaceful entry," "peaceful possession," and "peaceful enjoyment."

Answer (score 2):

*Peaceable* has a particular meaning in this instance.

**Peaceable possession**

> A continuous possession of property that is uninterrupted by legal
>   suits or other action intended to oust the possessor from the
>   property. Peaceable possession does not preclude there being adverse
>   claims against the possessor, so long as no actual attempt has been
>   made to dispossess him or her.

Read more at http://www.yourdictionary.com/peaceable-possession#eCmcMceoRsmIw9hX.99

Answer (score 0):

We are trying to educate our law students on the distinction so, like Max, I give them an example. If we leave a bar at 6 pm laughing and yelling and having a great, but loud, time, we are still acting peaceably albeit not peacefully. We aren't doing anything that is violent and could get us in trouble (maybe after 11:00 am the police might do something to keep the noise down, but not at 6 pm.) Whereas, if I leave the bar quietly and then start quietly tripping and hitting people, I may be acting quietly, but not peaceably...because I am using violence or force. I do like the Hitler analogy.

Comment: Hello, KiminCalifornia. 'We are trying to educate our law students on the distinction' begs the question being asked here. As Helmar has said in a comment above, '[In the OED], one definition of 'peaceable' is 'Free from conflict or dissent; peaceful', which is almost exactly the first definition of 'peaceful': 'Free from disturbance; tranquil'. Beware of selecting 'peaceful' sense 339 and 'peaceable' sense 112 (I exaggerate how many senses OED lists) and then claiming 'The distinction between 'peaceful' and 'peaceable' is ...'. You may, of course, have a legal register where definitions ...

Comment: are more rigorous, and OED 339 and 112 (or whatever) are the [only] accepted ones in legalese. But such narrowly scoped questions are off-topic on ELU, which deals largely  with general English usage. Here, FumbleFingers' first comment carries the most weight, though certainly connotations may differ significantly.

Comment: Hi, KiminCalifornia. I think that framing the question of how _peaceably_ and _peacefully_ differ in the context of their legal meanings is quite reasonable. Your answer would be stronger, however, if it cited definitions of the two words from a reputable reference work—whether OED, Merriam-Webster's, Black's Law Dictionary (if it covers the terms), or some other source. Even statutory definitions might be useful. Then your hypotheticals would serve a practical, supplementary role rather than having to carry the whole burden of the argument themselves.

Comment: @Sven Yargs I've lost where this was said, but providing a definition on ELU say that is at odds with one used in law may give grounds for legal action about the person / body so doing. Be that as it may, the legal definition/s may well be country-specific and hence essentially 'which style guide should I use?' / In this case, it's clear that OP is asking about general English usage, albeit giving an example from a legal document (and a dated one at that). '[T]he correct scope of meaning of each of the two words' (one of which does not appear in the example) demands a general (the OED) answer.

Answer (score 0):

For a well-spoken and well-educated group that wrote for posterity and carefully considered every word, look no further than our founding fathers and the First Amendment:

> Congress shall make no law respecting an establishment of religion, or prohibiting the free exercise thereof; or abridging the freedom of speech, or of the press; or the right of the people peaceably to assemble, and to petition the Government for a redress of grievances.

Comment: This does not in any way explain the difference between peacefully and peaceably.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/427925)

Answer (score -1):

"peaceful" is an adjective which can be applied to a person **or** an object, which means "at peace", ie calm, still, quiet, etc, and "peaceable" is an adjective which **can only be applied to a person**, and means "Inclined to try to keep the peace".

Ie, the first is a description of **behaviour** and the second a description of **motivation**.

Thus, Hitler was not *peaceable*, but when he was asleep he was *peaceful*.

This carries over into the abverb forms "peacefully" and "peaceably".  When Hitler sits in the planning room, listening to his generals discuss campaigns, he may sit peacefully but not peaceably.  He's thinking about war, even if he is still and quiet.

This is a bit of an extreme example, but hopefully you take my point.

With your example, to say that something has been "peacefully enjoyed" means that people have enjoyed it while being peaceful, ie quiet, calm etc.  To say that it has been "peaceably enjoyed" means that people have enjoyed it in such a way as to avoid creating any conflict.

This in turn suggests that there is or was some potential for conflict in the thing that was being enjoyed:  perhaps some of the parties involved could have complained about other people using it, for example, but decided not to in order to **remain peaceable**.

Comment: The OED disagrees and lists both words for both cases. Have a look at the synonym page. https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english-thesaurus/peaceable

Comment: As the ngram @FumbleFingers linked in the comments above suggests, is more like the usage switched from use of the one to the other

Comment: @Helmar ngrams can tell us how the meaning changes over time (perhaps), but that doesn't affect the original intended meaning of the text, which I believe **is** peaceable rather than peaceful, ie "without causing conflict".

Comment: But as it stands, it is just your opinion, and the dictionary supports the opposite.

Comment: @Helmar synonyms are not alternative definitions.  If a dictionary or thesaurus lists "peacable" as a synonym for "peaceful" that does not mean that the meaning is the same: it really just means that it's similar or related.

Comment: Still the two entries of the actually words do not support your description, as one definition of peaceable is **Free from conflict or dissent; peaceful**, which is almost exactly the first definition of peaceful: **Free from disturbance; tranquil**

Comment: The difference is subtle, but it's a valid distinction nonetheless.  As you say though, my answer is my opinion so let's just let it stand.

Answer (score -1):

The difference between peacefully and peaceably, is that one is a state, and the other is an intent. Peace is essentially social order. The opposite of order is chaos.

Peacefully- social order existing free of chaos.

Peaceably- act in a way that promotes social order, and doesn't create chaos.

People who want to live peacefully, need to act peaceably.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. This question already has an accepted answer. Please make it clear what your answer is adding that you think the earlier answers were missing.

Answer (score -1):

Peacefully denotes mental status, while peaceably (legally) denotes enjoyment of a thing without any external interruption.